# Using debounce with react don't fire function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash

I want to debounce a function in react,

```
import { debounce } from 'lodash';

<button onClick={this.handleClickDebounce}>Debounce click</button>

handleClickDebounce = () => {
    debounce(this.fire_something, 500);
  };
```

What's is wrong here? the function not even fired. I created a demo below

https://codesandbox.io/s/1r4k3r2z8l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
constructor() {
    super();

    this.handleClickDebounce = debounce(this.handleClick, 500)
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/yk421z3om9

Answer (score 1):

Do it in the `constructor`. In your example, you create debounced function every time when you click on the button. But function should be debounced only once.

Working example - https://codesandbox.io/s/rr6w91p3wo (open the console and try to click on the buttons).

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.handleClickDebounce = debounce(this.handleClick, 500);
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.fire_something();
  };

  fire_something = () => {
    console.log("fire");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Normal click</button>
        <br />
        <button onClick={this.handleClickDebounce}>Debounce click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```